# Reputation update problem on meta

Tags: bug

Right now, my reputation points on Meta are off from my reputation points on StackOverflow (but only by 40, so its recent gains). I have tried refreshing with no change.

Interestingly enough, if I open my profile page from meta, the bar at the top says the low number, my "big" number on the profile page says the low number, but my "StackOverflow" rep in "Accounts" is correct. This bug persists even if I open meta from a link on StackOverflow where my reputation is correct.

Obviously not a big issue, and it could just be a timed update thing, but I figured the SO team should know about it!

Comment: Yeah, dup of my question.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Makes sense, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just caching. Not a problem. Moving along now...

Comment: Cleared my cache, even opened a different browser, and its still the same. Or are you saying MSO is caching it?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yup. It's cached server-side.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/158100

Answer (score 4):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow ( **synchronized hourly** ), though you earn separate badges.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where this is officially stated? I assume it's in an FAQ or something, but I don't know where?

Comment: @Benubird http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta